# When displaying local images with react some images get glitchy randomly

Tags: html, css, reactjs

When I'm displaying local images in React some images get glitchy randomly. When I refresh the page it gets fixed. Most of the time this happens to the first image because I'm displaying a couple of images in my personal portfolio. Did anyone have this kind of problem before? I have used React dozens of times but never faced this. I tried compressing images and changing the image type to png, jpg and SVG but nothing worked. Any advice would be nice. Thank you!

Example image:

[image: example image]

Comment: This is not a React issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? Where should I look?